# Can most modern flip phones with Bluetooth capability normally be used with most Bluetooth keyboards?

Tags: bluetooth

My father has a flip phone with its excruciatingly slow single-finger keyboard. His service is with Verizon, so he probably got his phone through Verizon too.

He doesn't currently know what specific model phone he has, though I'm trying to find out. He's three hundred miles away and we can only talk over his phone or texting.

He's getting old and a traditional keyboard would be much easier for him to use.

Since I'm not a Verizon customer, I could only reach a Verizon sales rep, who probably doesn't have much technical knowledge, and not technical support.

The rep told me that Bluetooth capability in flip phones is for wireless headsets and Bluetooth keyboards are for smartphones/tablets.

In general, can most modern flip phones with bluetooth capability be used with most modern Bluetooth keyboards?

Comment: If it's the one with the foldable screen, yes, else, probably not

Answer (score 0):

Find out the make and model of the phone. Call the company that makes it and see if they can help. Do a Google search. Here is a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flipphones/comments/hjje01/bluetooth_keyboard_support_on_a_flip_phone/) on the topic.

Some do this but don't know if it will work for you. Call up Logitech or other bluetooth keyboard companies and provide them the make and model and ask them. Have your dad or you buy one and try it out. They still make flip phones but if his is really old I don't know.

Comment: But the OP said they couldnt fond out teh make and model.

Answer (score 0):

There are phones specifically designed for seniors, such as these. I got my father-in-law a similar phone for when his fingers became "too fat" for the keys (as he put it).

[image]
[image]